# Selected node ID in js tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

i'm currently using js tree and i want to get the last clicked checkbox id among other id.(i want to get the perticular check box id). #tree having ID and name

```
$("#tree").jstree("get_selected").each
                    (function () {
                        treeNodes.push(this.id);

                    });
```

this code is not giving any id.
how can i do it?

Comment: Is id defined as a variable somewhere? If you want to use it as a selector you might need $(this).attr('id'); 
I am not familiar with jstree

Comment: yah,i wanna to get the only the checked (clicked)item id  among other check nodes.that's my question?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: try `treeNodes.push($(this).attr('id'));`

Comment: i tried this also. no luck.any posibility for do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
        $("#arbol").jstree({
               "plugins": ["ui", "html_data", "checkbox", "themes"]
        });

        $("#arbol").bind('change_state.jstree', function (e, data) {
               codigosCheckBoxs()
        });
});

function codigosCheckBoxs() {
        var codigosList = [];
        $("#arbol").jstree("get_checked", null, true).each(function () {
                 if (this.id.length > 0) {
                      codigosList.push(this.id);
                 }
        });
       alert('Ids: ' + codigosList)
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="arbol">
<ul>
    <li><a>01 Sistema de Dirección</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a>0101 Volante de Dirección</a>

                <ul>
                    <li id="010101"> <a title="Estado y/o Fijación Deficiente">010101 Estado y/o Fijación Deficiente - G-M-L</a>

                    </li>
                    <li id="010102"> <a title="Juego Axial">010102 Juego Axial - G-M-L</a>

                    </li>
                    <li id="010103"> <a title="Juego Radial">010103 Juego Radial - G-M-L</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/BIPiane/dupru/